# iOS Push Notification Not Sending

Tags: ios, push-notification, urbanairship.com, dev-to-production

I've been developing an app with push notifications powered through UrbanAirship and its been working great for development. The problem is when I create an Ad Hoc build. The push notifications seem to stop working. I'm not sure where the breakdown occurs, but it just doesn't seem to be working.

I have already setup my app ID for both "development" and "production" push notifications and I've added the certificates before building and releasing. I am sure that I am using the proper app ID for my distribution mobile provision as well.

I don't know what could be going wrong. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I am getting the same issue. Did you ever resolve this? The devices are all registerring correctly with UA but the Overview section on UA website shows no data for pushes even though they should have been sending.

Comment: @EvanLayman Unfortunately, the notifications just started to work for seemingly no reason. I apologize that this surely isn't the response you were hoping for. Just ensure your certificates are set up properly and all of the ID values are correct.

Comment: I figured out my issue was that I had emailed UA to enable the device push's for my development application, but had forgotten to do so with my production/ad hoc app.

Comment: @EvanLayman Oh. Maybe mine was just a delay in enabling on UA's side. Thanks for the input!

Comment: I still haven't got mine working.. It's been a few days since they enabled the notifications for app pushes, and I re-uploaded my ad hoc certificate but no luck.

Comment: @EvanLayman It's brutal, because Apple has too many security measures. There are too many complications that online "solutions" sometimes just can't work. I've had some issues with that.